# google maps api reset layer on new query

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a function that display a layer based on a SQL Query where the user insert a parameter in a form. I would like to reinitialize (empty) the layer at each new query without using a reset button. Thank you if you can help me.

There is the function:

```
function CS_query() {
    CSsearch = document.getElementById('CS_Input').value;
    layer_imm = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
            select: 'geometry',
            from: '1ckqpE8ZxVzfgJ5bT-vAkpBwjVANbV-KiNjfScjw',
            where: "CODE_CS LIKE '%" + CSsearch + "%'"
        }
    }); 
    layer_imm.setMap(map);  
}
```

Comment: Instead of initializing new `FusionTablesLayer` with each user query, have you tried passing in the new query to the existing `FusionTablesLayer` object using `FusionTablesLayer.setOptions()`?

Comment: Your table is no longer public (or no longer exists). I agree with Gady.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers guys.

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('CS'),
    'click', CS_query);

layer_imm = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer();

function CS_query() {
    CSsearch = document.getElementById('CS_Input').value;
    layer_imm.setOptions({
        query: {
            select: 'geometry',
            from: '1_SY_lmkaQ3_3_pPDzho1-X9fc8WtdJGfo2w1VVg',
            where: "CODE_CS LIKE '%" + CSsearch + "%'"
        },
        map:map
    }); 

}

<input type="text" id="CS_Input">
<input type="button" id="CS" value="Submit" >
```

Comment: The answer is here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13821604/query-on-a-fusiontable-layer