# Query on a fusiontable layer

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a function that use a html form to do a query on a fusiontable layer. However, the query return all the features of the layer, not the query as it supposes to do. Can someone help me with this?

Here is the function:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('CS'),
    'click', CS_query);

layer_imm = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer('1_SY_lmkaQ3_3_pPDzho1-X9fc8WtdJGfo2w1VVg');

function CS_query() {
    CSsearch = document.getElementById('CS_Input').value;
    layer_imm.setOptions({
        query: {
            select: 'geometry',
            from: '1_SY_lmkaQ3_3_pPDzho1-X9fc8WtdJGfo2w1VVg',
            where: "CODE_CS LIKE '%" + CSsearch + "%'"
        },
        map:map
    }); 

}

<input type="text" id="CS_Input">
<input type="button" id="CS" value="Submit" >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create the layer without any options:

```
layer_imm = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer();
```